# Api to get all lists from mailchimp in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting all lists details from url: https://us17.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists
But its not like what i want. i am using and i want its route in api.php with get request and function in my controller where i can refer my routes and get all lists based on mailchimp api key which is stored in my database along with user_id but i dont want this from url link as i shown above.

I will be thankful if u give me any idea or useful link where i can find my this solution. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Its not the idea of SO to ask for some code or  link to a library. You should be able to find this by yourself by typing "Laravel" and "Mailchimp" into your favorite search engine. That being said, here is one Package which might help you. I did not use it by myself but packages from Spatie do what they promise.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-newsletter